# FullCalendar prevent event dropped outside of business hours

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using the FullCalendar plugin and trying to make it so you can't drop a new event when its being dragged into something that is outside of the business hours.  I have it so you can't drag into any date before the current date, but can't figure out how prevent say the weekend to be dragged to.

I don't want a hard coded solution where I have to do an if than statement specifically for the weekend because what if I want to add business hours say Wednesday on a specific week and only allow between 1pm and 4pm ? So I need a dynamic solution I could pass down some JSON like the events: handles and the businessHours can handle as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* initialize the external events
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {
        // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
        $(this).data('event', {
            title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
            stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
        });
        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        $(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
        });
    });
    /* initialize the calendar
    -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
        drop: function() {
            // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                $(this).remove();
            }
        },
        /* This constrains it to today or later */
        eventConstraint: {
            start: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            end: '2100-01-01' // hard coded must have
        },
        businessHours: {
            start: moment().format('HH:mm'), /* Current Hour/Minute 24H format */
            end: '17:00' // 5pm
        }
    });
});
```

here is a fiddle of my current example http://jsfiddle.net/htexjtg6/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

one problem you are having is because the initialized events doesn't have a duration - so fullcalendar doesn't know if the events overlap constraints and businessHours when dropped. Simply setting start/end can solve that.

```
$(this).data('event', {
    title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
    stick: true, // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
    start: moment(),
    end: moment(),
});
```

**bonus**: in the fullcalendar initializer set `defaultTimedEventDuration:'01:00:00',` (default duration of events is 2 hours)- set this value according to the domain the application applies to.

About having different times on different days; BusinessHours can be an array - (which could come from a function returning jsonarray (since jsonArrays are fully qualified js). see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/businessHours/

```
businessHours: [ 
    {
        dow: [ 1, 2, 3 ], // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
        start: '08:00', // 8am
        end: '18:00' // 6pm
    },
    {
        dow: [ 4, 5 ], // Thursday, Friday
        start: '10:00', // 10am
        end: '16:00' // 4pm
    }
],
eventConstraint:"businessHours",
```

see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/htexjtg6/11/ for a fork of your code (with working businessHours)

Comment: I had mentioned in the bounty wanting to be able to still drag the new event to the date even if it had a specific time restriction... possibly defaulting the time to the earliest one that's listed available during business hours.  Are you saying that this is impossible to do with FullCalendar and can only add events to the daily view?

Comment: @eqiz That is working in the fiddle, if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: I meant to mention the reference to being able to do it in a monthly view in the bounty.  I was meaning that part is what you are saying is impossible it can only be done using a weekly or daily view with dragging the event and not a monthly?

Comment: @eqiz If you look at the fiddle i posted, this is already working as requested. In the month view, you cannot drop events outside of businessHours(weekends).

Comment: @eqiz What you are looking for in the bounty should all be answered in the fiddle and in my answer - i've updated it a bit.
You can only drop events inside businessHours (which includes specific days for the month view) and the businessHours parameter takes an array which can come from a function.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass this **constraint: 'businessHours'** in event object.